# Time dilation and newton experiment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, time-dilation, history

If I drop a ball from **h** it will take  **T** time to reach ground now I drop the ball in a moving train from the same **h** this time the ball will go through a bigger path to reach the ground but time is equal to first experiment , so I say the time is relative and it goes slower in moving train .

so relativity and time dilation answer this question .

my question is that when *newton* write his law how he did not see this obvious situation ? I mean why this simple question " why time is equal in same velocity but different path?" did not come to his mind?

Comment: Because at that era they thought there was no speed limit, therefore time and length would not have to change. These effects only occur because light always travels at the same speed for every observer, meaning time and lengths have to shift to compensate for that fact

Comment: I did not talk about light speed my experiment is in a regular speed , the path increase in same velocity and same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with length contraction or time dilation . Just the ball in the second case has a 2nd velocity ( its horizontal velocity ) and this makes the path of the ball to be bigger , not time dilation , not length contraction.

Comment: thanks , I was all mistake